# CSS Font Not Formatting

Tags: html, css, fonts, colors, pycharm

I am beginning to code in HTML and CSS, and am using the FreeCodeCamp tutorials to help me. Along with my learning I am creating a simple webpage of my own as a project to work on.

Having learnt how to use fonts from the Internet in my webpage, I tried to change the font, colour and size of my header, but when I run the code, this doesn't show up on my webpage.

If it helps, I am using PyCharm for this (I'm not really sure what IDE to use- and I already use PyCharm so I though I'd continue with that).

```
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lobster"
      rel ="stylesheet" type="text/css">

<style> <!--Why doesn't this work?-->
   h1 {
    font-family: Lobster;
    font-size: 50px:
    color: red;
  }
</style>

<body>
<h1> This is the h1 text which should be formatted.</h1>
```

Comment: https://codepen.io/antonbks/pen/GRKjXwY Working as intended for me, are you sure there isn't another rule applied to h1 elsewhere? You can try adding `font-family: Lobster !important` to test

Comment: Voting to Close as this question was caused by a problem that can no longer be reproduced or a simple typographical error. While similar questions may be on-topic here, this one was resolved in a manner unlikely to help future readers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your CSS comment is wrong `/* CSS Comment */`

```
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lobster"
      rel ="stylesheet" type="text/css">

<style> /* Why doesn't this work? */
   h1 {
    font-family: Lobster;
    font-size: 50px;
    color: red;
  }
</style>

<body>
<h1> This is the h1 text which should be formatted.</h1>
</body>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/lalji1051/x0odt5qk/2/

Answer (score 1):

There is an error in your css at this line: `font-size: 50px:` should be `;` instead of `:` at the end of line.

Comment: Thank you! I changed the : but I'm still receiving the same unformatted text. I seperated this piece of code from the rest of my program but still was shown the unformatted text. On codepen.io/antonbks/pen/GRKjXwY I am able to see the change in font, not in colour, and on PyCharm, I'm not able to see either.

Comment: @CodeBeginner the codepen had the same syntax error, I forgot to fix it after seeing it in your code. https://codepen.io/antonbks/pen/GRKjXwY should be fixed now you can see the color change

Comment: The issue might be with your comment as pointed out by the newest answer. I have removed it in the codepen before starting.

Comment: Aha! That was it! Thank you for your help!